# Setting up cursors - children could not be evaluated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I want to set up different cursors depending on what mode or state my program is in. I set up a cursor utility class to accommodate the different states based on bools.

I'm going to break down the class to a small snippet to show you what I have set up.

Script that is attached to "RingSpawnPoint":

```
public void DrawLines(string num)
    {
        try{
            GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").GetComponent<CursorUtility>().number = num;
            GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").GetComponent<CursorUtility>().drawingCursor = true; //Exception happens here
            /* Other code omitted */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Item(ex);
        }
    }
```

So, when I call DrawLines and I pass in a string number like "1" or "2"... DrawLines("1") for example, I get an exception at the line indicated above and the exception is "Children could not be evaluated". I'm not sure why that occurs?

EDIT: for clarification, the CursorUtility class is not attached to any game object. Could doing something like below be an issue?
`GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").GetComponent<CursorUtility>();`

Comment: When you use the `GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").GetComponent<CursorUtility>()` could you assign it to a reference, then reuse this reference. It might not solve your problem but could be worth a try.

Comment: what do you mean by assign it to a reference?

Comment: Something like `CursorUtility cursorUtility = GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").GetComponent<CursorUtility>();` then `cursorUtility.number = num;` and `cursorUtility.drawingCursor = true;`

Comment: So it seems to be a problem with this part: " CursorUtility cursorUtility = GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").GetComponent<CursorUtility>(); "it looks like cursorUtility is null? Which is oddd??? This class does exist. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: If you break it down and just try and get the `GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint")` and assign it to a variable, is that also null? i.e. is the GameObject called "RingSpawnPoint (Clone)" or something?

Comment: wait, assign the gameobject to a variable?

Comment: Another question, do I have to attach my cursorUtility class to my game object in order to use it? no right? I think the problem is because the CursorUtility class is not attached to my game object.... That would be a problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach CursorUtility to your GameObject:

```
GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").AddComponent( "CursorUtility" ) as MonoBehaviour;
```

Comment: I think you're right, this could work but is there a solution where I don't have to attach the utility class to my game object and still use the methods if the state is true or false?

Comment: Well, I think this is the best solution, but, of course, you can link the Utility object to your gameObject in some other way, for example encapsulating your gameObject and add references to the utility object or keeping a map between the gameObject and the utility. It depends on your architecture.

Comment: Well, when I try your solution, I get CursorUtility is a type but used like a variable. Cannot convert to System.Type?

Comment: try AddComponent< CursorUtility >()

Comment: Okay, now it's "only assignment, call increment, decrement or new object expression can be used as a statment"

Comment: in the first form I forgot that the parameter must be a string: GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").AddComponent( "CursorUtility" ) as MonoBehaviour;. Sorry

Comment: GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").AddComponent( "CursorUtility" ) as MonoBehaviour; this line

Comment: something to do with "as monobehavior" Do I need this?

Comment: CursorUtility must be a MonoBehaviour in order to be attached to a GameObject

Comment: Btw, if I have several scripts that need to use cursorutility and I need to attach it to the game object in several methods, can I just set this line:  GameObject.Find("RingSpawnPoint").AddComponent("CursorUtility"); in start or update instead of inside several methods?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in Start. Not in update because you will not want to do it in each frame